# Use SQL CE 4 for user data store

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2010

is it possible to use the SQL ce 4 as a user data store and if yes do I still configure it the same way with aspnet_regsql?
Running vs2010 sp1 beta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sql CE 4 doesn't support store procedures, therefore asp.net membership can't be used with Sql CE 4.

Answer (score 2):

Codeplex hosts a project with a Membership provider for SQL CE 4 : http://sqlcemembership.codeplex.com/

(Also available as NuGet package)